# Oracle SQL Select Hex value to SHA256

Tags: sql, oracle, hex, oracle-sqldeveloper, sha256

There's a specific column (hex_values) on a table, where all the values (strings) are base16 (HEX) encoded.

Is it possible to SELECT all the members of hex_values and bring the result already SHA256 hashed?

For example:

```
 -------------------------
|       HEX_VALUES        |
 -------------------------
| 70617373776f7264313233a | //password123 (HEX)
 -------------------------  
| 31323370617373776f7264a | //123password (HEX)
 ------------------------- 
| 6c6f72656d697073756d    | //loremipsum (HEX)
 ------------------------- 
| 6d7970617373776f7264    | //mypassword (HEX)
 -------------------------
```

And the SQL Query would do all the job, like this (row 1 example):

70617373776f7264313233a (string HEX) → password123 (regular string) → sha256(password123) (giant string)

So the result from this SQL Query would be:

```
 -------------------------
|       HEX_VALUES        |
 -------------------------
| sha256(password123)     | 
 -------------------------  
| sha256(123password)     | 
 ------------------------- 
| sha256(loremipsum)      | 
 ------------------------- 
| sha256(mypassword)      | 
 -------------------------
```

I know I can :

1) Select hex_values (Oracle SQL)

2) After SQL Query: Transform to Regular String → SHA256(Regular String)

But I >really< need to do this without using any other source code besides Oracle SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 12 and above there's the [`standard_hash()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions183.htm#SQLRF55647) function you could use. Use [`hextoraw()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions073.htm#SQLRF00649) on the strings, then pass that value to `standard_hash()`.

```
SELECT standard_hash(hextoraw(hex_values), 'SHA256')
       FROM elbat;
```

And by the way, SHA256 is a hashing algorithm not an encryption algorithm. So there is no such thing as "SHA256 encrypted" values.

Comment: Thank you so much! ♥

Comment: After all, this is what worked for me:

`SELECT 
standard_hash(
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW(NAME)),
  'SHA256'
) 
FROM ELBAT`

Answer (score 0):

After all, this is what worked for me:

```
 SELECT 
    standard_hash(
      UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(HEXTORAW(HEX_VALUES)),
      'SHA256'
    ) 
    FROM ELBAT
```